# Python 3: search for a specific string in a file

Tags: python

I have a txt file with strings assigned to each other like "sun - moon" and I want to get the assigned value (no matter which one) of a particular string if it would come from user input, and if not then create a new pair for file and write it to it:

```
user_input = input()

if user_input in open('base.txt').read():
    print(True) # it's just to be sure that everything really works
else:
    base_file = open('base.txt', 'a+')
    base_file.write(user_input)
    base_file.write('\n')
    base_file.close()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You have a file with key pairs like a dictionary accept text and you want to search for "sun" and return "moon"?  If that is correct, I would consider using pickle.

Comment: Yes, that is right. I just don't know where to move to fulfill it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pickle

myDictA = {'sun': 'moon'}

with open('myFile.pkl', 'w') as file:
    pickle.dump(myDict, file)

with open('myFile.pkl', 'r') as file:
    myDictB = pickle.load(file)

print("myDictA:", myDictA)
print("myDictB:", myDictB)
```

you can also integrate gzip in the file save load process to save disk space if you want.  Another option is to use `cPickle` which should be written the same way and is said to be up to 1000x faster.

Answer (score 0):

A little addition to the current code.

```
user_input = input()
flag=1
with open('base.txt') as f:
  data=f.read()
  if user_input in data:
    print(data)
    flag=0
if flag:
  base_file = open('base.txt', 'a+')
  base_file.write(user_input)
  base_file.write('\n')
  base_file.close()
```